# Do LED have an unproductive base power consumption like incandescent bulbs?

Tags: led, semiconductors

To generate light from an incandescent body, like a tungsten filament,
the body needs to be heated up to a temperature minimum needed to emmit light from that material.

Up to that minimum temperature, only heat is emitted. Above it, heat and light is emmitted.

What is the related behaviour of LED?

When the current increases from 0 A to the specified standard current, I assume there is some range where the LED does not emmit any light.

What happens in that range - I would guess it's not behaving just as a resistor?

Comment: LEDs emit light (in tiny quantities) even with tiny currents. Try it yourself in a dark room.

Comment: Red LEDs are about 40% power efficient too. Incandescent lamps are about 2% and fluorescents about 8%. White LEDs are not too fantastic at about 10%.

Comment: LED's can be driven by PWM even at small pulse widths. This isn't even possible with incandescents because of the thermal delay. This can drive the _average_ current down even further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Early LEDs had a kind of knee below which you didn't get much light out of them, and thus a sort of threshold current (maybe 1mA). Most modern LEDs will output light with microamperes of current, and are reasonable efficient at low currents. As current increases the efficiency will peak at some current then decrease as I^2R losses increase, but I think it's pretty constant from (say) 10%  (maybe even 1%) to 100% of the recommended operating current. Here's an early (2001) white LED with a relatively high minimum current (from [this web page](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?89607-White-LED-lumen-testing))

[image]

And another that is better (2007 Nichia)

[image]

Modern LEDs are almost never operated at the optimum level for **efficiency**- the main thing is to get many lumens out of the expensive semiconductor as practical.

You'd get more attractive looking curves if you plotted lumens/mA but that's not representative of energy efficiency- the forward voltage drop increase with current.

Comment: White LEDs may behave differently than directly emitting (monochrome) LEDs because of the additional yellow emitting phosphor. I've seen graphs showing the colour balance varies with current, suggesting that the phosphor may be less linear than the blue LED.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at a typical LED [datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/LTST-C190GKT-Lite-On-datasheet-7279162.pdf). Figure 4 showers relative luminous intensity versus applied current. It is assumed that the voltage is fixed here and the diode is forward biased. We see then that any amount of current creates visible light. So an LED does not have the same dead area of an incandescent light bulb. However, seeing the non-linear curve, we recognize that there is an optimal current for lighting efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You get this kind of [image: Brightness v current] graph. It's pretty linear all the way down.

It behaves like a semiconductor junction. A particular voltage level is needed to push charge across the band gap. However, every electron-hole recombination emits a photon. This is independent of temperature and everything else, so there's no real minimum.

Comment: Why is the X axis time?

Comment: @immibis: different currents are being applied at different times. There is no other relationship between time and current or time and power.

Comment: @immibis, because that's how they tested it.  They set the current to a certain level and held it there for a certain length of time to get a good average.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real minimum LED current needed to get light output in modern LEDs due to their extremely low leakage Old LED technology had surface leakage issues and was inefficient so we would always drive them well     I have used standard general purpose optocouplers in the microamp range proving that the LED must be making light